# How can the following codes be generalized for plotting the countplots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a df that has 5 categorical values and I am doing the following the count the number of values and then plot them:

```
data['yr'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(x = 'yr', data = data)

data['season'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(x = 'season', data = data)

data['holiday'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(x = 'holiday', data = data)

data['workingday'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(x = 'workingday', data = data)

data['weathersit'].value_counts()
sns.countplot(x = 'weathersit', data = data)
```

In this case there are only 5 columns, so this technique was not cumbersome. But if there are many such features, writing like this will be highly cumbersome. So, I would like to know how can I modify the above code to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you loaded your dataframe using pandas you could use this piece of code which will also get you a list of all the column names in your

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


data = pd.read_csv('cars.csv' , ';')

# Gets you the list of all columns in your dataframe.
columns = list(data.columns.values.tolist())
print(columns)


for column in columns:
    data[column].value_counts()
    sns.countplot(x = column, data = data)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Do add a separator in the pd.read_csv and check if the columns list stores out the column name properly because not specifying the separator might sometimes cause to save all the columns as a single entity and  you would be able to see only one plot having all column names together.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
columns = ["yr","season","holiday","workingday","weathersit"]

for column in columns:
    data[column].value_counts()
    sns.countplot(x = column, data = data)
```

Comment: This just outputs one plot and not the plots of all the columns